# Setting up Graylog: where should the log server be and how do clients acces it?

Tags: logging, graylog

I've been perusing the Graylog website, but it all feels so dense and there's so much talk about various tools and protocols. I could really use some help in baby language.

I'm struggling to know how to start integrating Graylog (or any log management tool for that matter.) I've got a web application set up on a customer's server from which I would like to send logs. I could probably install Graylog on the same server, but I'm sure it's better to have Graylog on my own server, so that multiple customer applications can all log to it, but how do the logs make it to the log server?

Should I be using TCP or HTTP or copying log files to the log server over SSH?

EDIT:
The customer's running IIS with asp.net mvc and logging is done with log4net.

Comment: What kind of web server is the customer running (eg. tomcat/spring) and which mechanism is used to currently write the log to disk (eg. log4j, sl4j)?

Comment: @DanTorrey I've edited the question with that info.